# HP Spectre 13-ak0xxx Cursor seems to auto-click on everything

Tags: mouse, touchpad

On HP Spectre Folio Convertible 13-ak0xxx: with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) cursor seems to auto-click on everything, I pass it over immediately. I checked accessibility and click assist is off so it isn't that. Confirmed by disabling my touch-pad and a USB mouse does the same thing. It clicks rapidly as confirmed by highlighting text but it also seems to be random as it unselects and selects at different, but still rapid, interval. start to happen past one week or so. anyone know anything about this issue? please let me know.

````
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      
id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:16                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:16          id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-touch:16                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-tablet stylus:16             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-tablet eraser:16                 id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-tablet cursor:16             id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard            id=5   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:16                  id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)] ```
 
not allowing me to past or copy text, just rapidly clicking everything most of the time.
````

Comment: Please give the output of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6231/524752 . Since it's selecting text rapidly, I suspect a hardware problem. You would need to find a workaround to disable that button.

Comment: @DanielT it is really hard to write or do anything,

Comment: Does disabling tap to click in setting work?

Comment: @DanielT I did that too, it is not working, even i disable the pad and used USB mouse with that mouse it do more ward behavior.

Comment: Please do `sudo apt install evtest`. Then pick the device for your touchpad after `sudo evtest`. Repeat for all devices until you find which one is sending the clicks, then post the lines related to the click.

Comment: greetings @DanielT sorry reply after long time, I see some error here
```type 1 (EV_KEY), code 325 (BTN_TOOL_FINGER), value 1``` and
 ```type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 1``` and
```type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1
 ```

Comment: `-1` is not necessarily an error, in this case it seems to be the mouse up event. Please run `evtest` for each plausible device, and note down whether you see terminal output happen at the moment the auto-clicks happen. This will tell whether the kernel/hardware is problematic. Then run `xev` and see when it happens and if you know which device it's printing. This will tell if X11 or your desktop environment is problematic. If not, it could be the apps themselves or an accessibility option

Comment: @DanielT I try both ways, the cursor move to the right side half way bottom of the window it do not register any thing both in ```evtest``` nor in ```xev``` it is just moving to the side and starts clicking without any change in terminal. Also only touch click on the pad is working both right click and left click push button on pad is not working. when i move the white box to the side where the mouse move and on other windows i start working then the mouse always move back to the right side.

Comment: this is the registration of ```xev``` after moving the white box in right side half way butom where the mouse move ```ConfigureNotify event, serial 34, synthetic YES, window 0x1600001,
    event 0x1600001, window 0x1600001, (2101,1660), width 346, height 332,
    border_width 2, above 0x0, override NO

PropertyNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    atom 0x13f (_GTK_EDGE_CONSTRAINTS), time 27855526, state PropertyNewValue```

Comment: Btw you have to hover on the xev window. I'm surprised about "the mouse always move back to the right side". You can either unplug any joysticks, or find which program is messing with you. If it's "without any change in terminal", then you should look in your accessibility settings and see whether any "dwell click / timing" settings are enabled

Comment: @DanielT I thought the same, before i use to scroll the page with two-finger scrolling, and i felt it is because of this, so I disable two-finger scrolling and start to use Edge Scrolling, the system started act normal but after 24 hours it become metal again. Btw when i try to hold a window and MOVE it to the side or change place this mouse behavior become more and more dramatic.

Comment: A solution to a separate question suggested removing `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

Comment: @DanielT the problem is still the same ```$ sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics -y``` and 
```Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
After this operation, 204 kB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 226207 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing xserver-xorg-input-synaptics (1.9.1-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...```

Comment: I'm mostly out of ideas. "24 hours it become metal again. Btw when i try to hold a window": This might be the touchpad failing to calibrate its voltage thresholds, so noise is picked up as clicks, and it happened to my touchscreen driver too. How to fix this or why I don't know

Comment: @DanielT sorry man, but now i have two pointer in my desktop, it is funny. before it hide it self and went to the corner now one courser is with me and the second one is doing  movements and clicking in the corner. I think after 4 years i should move back to window it is taking too much time to solve issues with ubuntu now a days. but thanks

Comment: "two pointer": Someone might have plugged in a tablet or malware: https://old.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/16corgr/you_can_have_two_cursors_my_mind_was_blown_i_just/ . I recommend you test from the LiveUSB whether this still occurs